# Javascript didn't return false

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

My doDelete() function didn't return false when i click cancel. It works perfectly when i click OK, my data can be deleted. When i click 'cancel' it go into blank page. I seriously don't have any idea what s wrong with my code..

below is my javascript code and my delete image :

```
<input type="image" src="img/delete.png" title="Delete User" name="delete" id="delete" onclick="doDelete(<%=rs.getInt("id")%>);"/>

function doDelete(id){      
    var r=confirm("Are you sure want to delete this user?");
    if (r==true){       
    document.forms["form"]["action"].value="delete";
    document.forms["form"]["recordId"].value=id;
    document.form.submit();     
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: May be because you are submitting the form before returning!

Comment: An input type image is a submit button by default, so you need explicitly return false to the handler `... onclick="return doDelete(...)"...`. Better to add the listener to the form's submit handler so if the form is submitted by other means it will still be confirmed.

Comment: thanks RobG!! Already can return false! thank you so much :D

Comment: i changed my input type image like this : onclick="return doDelete();" and it works now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<form onsubmit="return doConfirm();"...>
```

and the function:

```
function doConfirm() {
  var response = confirm('Do you really want to submit?');
  if (response) {
    // do stuff
  }
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do

```
if(r == true) {
///you code
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code path does not return any value when `r == true` try simplest and most cleanest possible way

```
var response = confirm("Are you sure want to delete this user?");
if (response) {

    document.forms["form"]["action"] = "delete";
    document.forms["form"]["recordId"].value = id;
    document.form.submit();
}

return response;
```

Comment: thanks @Pilot i already updated my code as your code, but still go into blank page :(

Comment: @aween change `document.forms["form"]["action"].value="delete";` to `document.forms["form"]["action"] = "delete";`

Comment: no, it is UserListing.jsp actually. When submit it goes to servlet page that has the delete code. problem now is only with the javascript...

Comment: @aween then set `document.forms["form"]["action"] = "UserListing.jsp"`